# Download files/videos from url and write them to disk without prompting save location dialoge using chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am writing a chrome app which needs to download videos from urls in background after specific time intervals.

Unlike chrome extension ( which has chrome.downloads api to deal with downloads ) chrome.downloads in not available for chrome apps.
If I use filesystem api, it shows the save location dialogue which I do not want. As, I need downloads to be dealt in the backgorund.

Is there any work around for this requirement ?

Comment: I guess you'll have to write a separate extension and use cross-extension messaging.

Comment: I am writting a chrome app for chrome os which keeps running in the background (kiosk app ). Is it possible to call an extension from background running chrome app ?

Comment: Like I said, cross-extension messaging. You can keep both your app and the extension in background by using the `"background"` in `"permissions"`